# Best way to dim/disable a div in Material-UI?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

In my app, I have `div`s that I want to dim and disable mouse events for, depending on component state - for example, loading. The initial method I came up with is to have a helper function that returns an inline style for dimming an element and disabling pointer events on it, given a boolean value:

```
const disableOnTrue = (flag) => {
    return {
        opacity: flag ? 0.15 : 1,
        pointerEvents: flag ? "none" : "initial"
    }
}
```

and using it on elements as such:

```
{loading && {/** render a loading circle */}}
<div style={disableOnTrue(this.state.loading)}>{/** stuff to be dimmed & disabled while loading */}</div>
```

In the disabled `div`, there are Material-UI `Button`s. However, it turns out that they don't care if `pointerEvents` are disabled on their parent `div`, and remain clickable, which is a big problem. So, on the `Button`s I had to set `disabled={loading}`. Then, this dims the `Button`s themselves, which unnecessarily compounds with the lowered `opacity` of `disableOnTrue`, meaning I would need to add some custom styling to ameliorate that; I want the entire `div` to be disabled, not for the `Button` to look especially disabled.

I've also tried using the [Backdrop](https://material-ui.com/components/backdrop/) component from Material, but couldn't get it to dim anything but the entire viewport.

Before I implement any sort of hacky solution throughout my entire app, I figured I should ask here to see if there is a clean way to achieve this that I'm missing. I've looked for quite a while, but haven't found anything.

Comment: Use material-ui [styling](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) and CSS classnames of the MUI elements you are using?

Comment: @DrewReese could you elaborate a bit on how this could help with my issue?

Comment: I believe the issue you may face is with the opacity, but by using the style APIs of MUI you can directly access/style the DOM elements used versus using the large blunt div to affect all wrapped elements equally. Many MUI components also already take a disabled prop to "grey them out" or make them otherwise uninteractable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I split the concept of "disabling" into two functions:

```
const dimOnTrue = (flag) => {
    return {
        opacity: flag ? 0.15 : 1,
    }
}

const disableOnTrue = (flag) => {
    return {
        pointerEvents: flag ? 'none' : 'initial'
    }
}
```

to be used on divs that should be dimmed and inputs that should be disabled, respectively.

Answer (score -2):

use sx props or style in material to disable

```
<Box sx={{ opacity: <contidion> ? 0.5 : 1,pointerEvents:<contidion> ? "none" : "auto"}}/>
```

you can use this way any kind of `div/tag` in html